# Reorganizing nested loops for multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to rewrite the main loop in a physics simulation and split the workload between more threads.
It calls `dostuff` on every unique pair of indices and looks like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        dostuff(i, j);
    }
}
```

I came up with two options:

```cpp
//#1
//sqrt is implemented as binary search on ints, floors the result
for (int x = 0; x < n * (n - 1) / 2; ++x)
{
    int i = (1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * x)) / 2;
    int j = x - i * (i - 1) / 2;
    dostuff(i, j);
}
//#2
for (int x = 0; x < n * n; ++x)
{
    int i = x % n;
    int j = x / n;
    if (i < j)
        dostuff(i, j);
}
```

And for each option, there is corresponding thread loop using shared atomic `counter`:

```cpp
//#1
while(int x = counter.fetch_add(1) < n * (n - 1) / 2)
{
    int i = (1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * x)) / 2;
    int j = x - i * (i - 1) / 2;
    dostuff(i, j);
}
//#2
while(int x = counter.fetch_add(1) < n * n)
{
    int i = x % n;
    int j = x / n;
    if (i < j)
        dostuff(i, j);
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to share the workload of the main loop between threads for `n < 10^6`?
EDIT:

```cpp
//dostuff
Element& a = elements[i];
Element& b = elements[j];
glm::dvec3 r = b.getPosition() - a.getPosition();
double rv = glm::length(r);
double base = G / (rv * rv);
glm::dvec3 dir = glm::normalize(r);
glm::dvec3 bd = dir * base;
accelerations[i] += bd * b.getMass();
accelerations[j] -= bd * a.getMass();
```

Comment: I would start with `std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, ...)` (on either or both loops), or something similar from TBB.

Comment: How to split the workload is very dependent on your hardware and operating system, as well as how much actual work `doStuff` does.

Comment: ~30 double multiplications, 2 sqrt & 2 writes and reads to/from vector is what doStuff does.

Comment: @Niik what OS and compiler are you using? There are vendor specific libraries for concurrency

Comment: Since you have vector access, try to split the workload such that each thread accesses the same "neighborhood" in memory. This will reduce cache misses, which can have a large performance impact

Comment: @Eyal I'm targetting linux and windows, g++ under linux, msvc under windows.

Comment: You may have to check in the code what OS you are on and enable different parts depending on that. Windows has PPL for this, I'm not sure what linux has

Answer (score 0):

Your work is a triangle.  You want to.divide the triangle into k distinct pieces.

If k is a power of 2 you can do this:

```
a
a a
b c d
b c d d
```

Each of those regions are equal in size.